# p:autocomplete tag using database

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete

I want to use autocomplete in inputTextArea. I am doing it using values from the database. I have words, digits, symbols(like #) stored in the database.

The problem is when I try typing in the textArea, the whole list of things appears. Instead, I just want only those options to come which matches the input written in the textArea, kind of autocomplete feature but it fetches values from a database. 
Given below is the java code that I have written so far.

```
public class DbConnect {


    public List<String> completeArea(String query1) {

        ResultSet rs;
        Statement st;
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement pst;
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/company", "root", "");

            try {
                query1 = "select name from labels";
                pst = con.prepareStatement(query1);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    result.add(rs.getString("name"));
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("error occured" + ex);
        }
        System.out.println("size is " + result.size());
        return result;
    }
```

I do not want to specify any particular letter for searching in the database, it should pick automatically when the user types in.  Any help would do good. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where are you using `String query` ? Is this hold the letter typed by user ?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I have edited the code now. That was String query1

Comment: The change in the title does not reflect the first alinea... Please 'make up your mind' ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje I changed the title because it was written that ''you can change the title of your question which has zero or low reputation''. So I did. Though the issue is resolved now.

Comment: Yes, but a change should be an improvement. It was not.

Comment: @Kukeltje okay, then you may suggest for this :p

Comment: The original title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the `query1` parameter of the `completeArea` method is the user input but you overwriting it with your query. Try with

```java
public List<String> completeArea(String input) {
   ...
   String query = "select name from labels where name like ?";
   pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
   pst.setString(1, input + "%");
   ...
}
```

Edited according to @Slaw comment. Thanks for the correction. :)

---

<strike>I would use `<p:autoComplete />` instead of inputTextArea for this usecase.</strike>

You can find a good tutorial in the [official PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) site.

Comment: If I make the changes which you have recommended, the list which was earlier coming, now does not come at all. Also regarding the <p: autoComplete /> tag, I am not using it because I need a big textarea, not just a single line input field.

Comment: I am not 100% sure about my sql syntax. Can you print out the value of the `query1` parameter?

Comment: If you're going to use a `PreparedStatement` (which you should) then the SQL should be `select name from labels where name like ?`. Then you'd call `pst.setString(1, input + "%")` to set the parameter.

Comment: @Sonney If you have a big text area, what do you end up passing as input? The whole contents of the text area? I'm assuming you only want to suggest completions for the latest word the user is typing—you'll need to extract that (incomplete) word. I'd help more but I have minimal experience with JSF.

Comment: Yes, this is why I suggested the `autoComplete` instead of the `inputTextarea`. Autocomplete usually works with a few characters and not with a whole sentence. The `completeArea` method will be called whenever a user stop typing in the input field and the parameter of the method should be the value of the field.

Comment: @Slaw Actually I am creating a custom code editor, so in that, I need to write the code and I want to write it with the help of auto-completion. That is the reason I am using inputTextArea. Yes I want to complete the latest word being typed by the user to autocomplete.

Comment: @Slaw what will come after like in place of this ?

Comment: The value for that placeholder will be provided with the following command that @Slaw already commented here.
`pst.setString(1, input + "%")`

Comment: Also I was able to reproduce this in an example project and the parameter of the `completeArea` is the latest word that was typed by the user. You can print out the value of this variable. If you use the above mentioned sql query you have to get back the proper data.

Comment: @Rashin   Thank you so very much for your efforts. It really worked. :)

Comment: @Slaw 
Thanks to you too for your help and suggestions.

Comment: @Slaw I need one more small help. What can we use to clear what the user has just typed and rather select from the dropdown list?

If I type 'se' for 'house'. the dropdown list shows house but after selecting house from the list, 'se' should now get clear and house should come as a result on the textarea. Till now it shows 'seuse' as a result.

Comment: okay. Thanks a lot. I did make a new question, no one answered.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is

```
select name from labels
```

that will give all labels's name...

> I do not want to specify any particular letter for searching in the database, it should pick automatically when the user types in. Any help would do good.

If you want some matching you must specify a condition

Comment: I don't know too much of programming. Very new to it. What type of condition shall I look for?

Comment: You can provide the user input, so you only get the name which start with the given string.

Comment: You must extract the word of the user is tipping and use sql query to find a word whose matc

select name from labels where name like 'hell%'

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: @Alexandre Actually, I know this like syntax. But the problem is how to extract the letter the user has typed?

Comment: @Rashin How? That is my question?

Comment: I don't know what you use as front-end. You must extract in the front end the letters, send it to the back-end and give it as parameter to your completeArea method

Comment: What kind of GUI are you using? JSF? Swing?

Comment: i am using JSF- primefaces

Comment: <h:form>
          <p:inputTextarea  id = "input" rows="10" cols="50" value = "#{username.d}"  
                             completeMethod="#{dbConnect.completeArea}" queryDelay="1" minQueryLength="1">
                <f:converter converterId = "www" />
            </p:inputTextarea>
         
            
            <h:commandButton value = "submit" action = "result"/>
        
           
        </h:form>


This is my t111.xhtml file